How to Use Siri on Apple Watch to send a Mail?
I'm able to Use Siri on Apple Watch, for example to set timers, reminders and even send messages. But when I try to send an email, I get the error:

Sorry, I can't help with emails here.

I'm using watchOS 10, on wifi, etc. and already tried restarting it.


Not a perfect solution, but I was able to do it through the Shortcuts app.

Open the Shortcuts app on the iPhone
Select ⌚ Apple Watch, then + (top, right) to add a new shortcut
Search for Mail, then select Send Email
Setup your shortcut; see Shortcuts User Guide
Make sure your watch is connected to the phone and give it some time to sync
Double check the new shortcut is available on the watch; test it using Siri

